# How to keep the thread free while executing an sql command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

So I have loooooooong stored procedure. It takes about 5-8 mins to execute.
Say I create a an sqlCommand object and execute it via my my asp.net application, The thread will wait until the command execution is complete or command timeout duration.

Event If I another thread (thread_2) to accomplish this task, thread_2 will wait. I want to avoid waiting because command is going to take about 4-7 mins to execute.

Is there any way to do that ?

**EDIT :**

correct me If I am wrong, 
but I believe using the asynchronous version will also use thread_2.
Asynchronous methods are just a wrapper to reduce threading code. [my belief]

I wanted some event driven mechanism, so that no thread is in use until the command execution is complete.

But now It feels that I am asking for too much... Am I ?

Comment: Use the asynchronous version(s) of ExecuteNonQuery...

Comment: correct me If I am wrong, 
but I believe using the asynchronous version will also use thread_2.
Asyncronous methods are just a wrapper to reduce threading code. [my belief]

I wanted some event driven mechanism, so that no thread is in use until the command execution is complete.

But now It feels that I am asking for too much... Am I ?

Comment: Well something has to wait. I believe BeginExecuteNonQuery allows you to specify a callback for when the stored procedure completed (successfully or otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make SQL calls asynchronous there are Async versions of all commands - i.e. [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonqueryasync.aspx)

The second part is to make page rendering asynchronous to not use thread while execution of the SQL command is in progress. Both MVC and WebForms allow you to do that (MVC is easier). Note that if execution is as long as you said you may want to implement some sort of poling mechanism on the page instead of waiting for request competition to render results...

With some code you can wrap it in `async`-friendly code ( [Using async / await](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2012/01/15/using-async-await.aspx) ) to use in [async MVC actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=VS.98%29.aspx).

If you have to stick with WebForms/plain ASP.Net you will need to do more work to implement asynchronous pages, but it is still possible.

Comment: correct me If I am wrong, 
but I believe using the asynchronous version will also use thread_2.
Asyncronous methods are just a wrapper to reduce threading code. [my belief]

I wanted some event driven metchanism, so that no thread is in use untill the command execution is complete.

But now It feels that I am asking for too much... Am I ?

Comment: @bilalfazlani, most asynchronous methods are relying on some other mechanisms to be notified of result rather than waiting on another thread. I'm not sure how exactly SQL async operations are implemented (also I'd be very surprised if there is thread allocated and waiting for each async operation).

Comment: check [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45) article

Comment: @Alexei, why do you say `WinForms`? you meant WebForms, right? Here is another one that I've saved on the subject (because ultimately he will have to do something while waiting, IMO) [link](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html)